# State stored in localStorage gets overwritten on page refresh in React redux? How to persist state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage

I'm adding user-objects to a users array Like so, users : [{}, {}, .....]. eventually this list of users is rendered to the UI. All fine so far, however every time I refresh the page and want to add a new user-object to the users array it overwrites the existing array and clears the UI. Ofcourse I want the data to persist and stay visible in the UI.
I would like to persist state with react-redux in localStorage to achieve this. The code below shows what I've done so far.

```
// Store
 const reducer = combineReducers({
    cats: getCatReducer,
    users: registerReducer,
})

const persistedState = loadState();

const initialState = {
    cats: {cat: []},
    users: {users:[]},
    persistedState,
}

const store = configureStore(
    {
        reducer,
        initialState,
        middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(thunk),
    })

store.subscribe(() => {
    saveState(store.getState());
});

export default store


//LocalStorage
    export const loadState = () => {
    try {
        const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
        if (serializedState === null) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return JSON.parse(serializedState);
    } catch (err) {
        return undefined;
    }
};

    export const saveState = (state) => {
        try {
            const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
            localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
        } catch (error) {
            // ignore write errors
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    };
    
   
//Action
     export const register = (user) => (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: user })
    }


//Reducer
 export const registerReducer = (state = { users: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case REGISTER_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true };
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            let user = action.payload
            return { ...state, users: [...state.users, user], loading: false };
        case REGISTER_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

//screen component
   const UserScreen = () => {

    const users = useSelector(state => state.users.users)

   return (
        <>
            {users.map((user, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={user.id} className={styles.userInfo}>
                        <div className={styles.user}> {user.name}</div>
                        <div className={styles.user}>{user.address}</div>
                        <div className={styles.user}>{user.country}</div>
                        <div className={styles.user}>{user.email}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
       </>
    )
}

 //LocalStorage log

 JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')) -->
     {users: {...}}
     {
     "users": [
        {
            "id": "89526872-8b33-46f4-86a2-faa83ae9686f",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john@example.com",
            "address": "SandyRoad 456",
            "country": "USA",
            "password": "123"
        },
        {
            "id": "400a4226-c287-415a-b6af-4d119dc75e79",
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "email": "jane@example.com",
            "address": "Hill 78",
            "country": "USA",
            "password": "123"
        }
    ],
    "loading": false
}

//Redux DevTools (raw) before refreshing the page!

    {
  cats: {
    cat: []
  },
  users: {
    users: [
      {
        id: '89526872-8b33-46f4-86a2-faa83ae9686f',
        name: 'John Doe',
        email: 'john@example.com',
        address: 'SandyRoad 456',
        country: 'USA',
        password: '123'
      },
      {
        id: '400a4226-c287-415a-b6af-4d119dc75e79',
        name: 'Jane Doe',
        email: 'jane@example.com',
        address: 'Hill 78',
        country: 'USA',
        password: '123'
      }
    ],
    loading: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're not initializing your state correct. The `persistedState` will be another property in your redux state (you should be able to see it in the redux dev tools). What you probably try to achieve is overwriting the empty `cats` and `users` properties. Changing

```js
const initialState = {
    cats: cat: [],
    users: [],
    persistedState,
}
```

to

```js
const initialState = {
    cats: cat: [],
    users: [],
    ...persistedState,
}
```

should work.

Comment: thanks. I tried changing the initialState property to ...persistedState. But to no success.

Comment: Ok. Could you provide either a CodeSandbox/REPL/... or show how your localState (browser dev tools) & redux store (redux-dev tools extension for browser) looks like?

Also `const users = useSelector(state => state.users.users)` seems to have one level of `users` to much

Comment: I added the Redux DevTool state and localStorage log to my post. Note, that this is before refreshing the page. After refreshing the redux store is empty, UI is cleared but localStorage persist?  When I add a new user after refreshing localStorage gets overwritten. At that point there is only one user stored in localStorage and one visible in UI.

Comment: Sorry, can't provide a sandbox there is an issue with 'react-dom/client'

Comment: no problem, it still seems like loading fails. I would console.log/debug the catch statement in `loadState`. Also what does the first line in your localStorage log mean? Are there two user properties or is the part below a serialization of the first line?

Comment: Can't figure it out. I guess it's easier to store them in a database and fetch them from the server. 
To answer your question, accessing the users array you need users.users otherwise you get an error. Thanks again @Adrian!